# Cannot Hibernate - Power policy manager error

Tags: windows, corruption, hibernate

I run Windows XP.

When I try to "Enable Hibernation" from Control Panel --> Power Options, 
I get the following error.

> Power policy manager unable to reserve hibernate file. The file or
>   directory is corrupt and unreadable

I see lots of solutions posted , but most of them involve deleting some system file, or accessing the registry.
Is there any way I can avoid such things and enable hibernation?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not, no.

hiberfil.sys is the file used to save the contents of your RAM and "hibernate" the system.  It's also marked as a system file, because, well, it is one.  If it's corrupted and needs to be deleted or have its permissions editted, then you're going to have to delete or edit a "system" file.

Incidentally, I'm of the opinon that on a site for IT professionals, we probably shouldn't see such a strong desire to avoid changing files with an arbitrary "system" flag... maybe SuperUser is more your speed?

Comment: OK! sorry about that.  guess I sounded too noobish :(
Anyway I can't delete the hiberfil file now.   Says `the file is corrupt and unreadable`
Any pointers on that?

Comment: Check permissions, try the command line, try safe mode... worst case, boot into another OS with a liveCD or what have you, and delete it through that.

Comment: Ok. I did the simple thing. Ran a Check Disk on my C: drive. 
Worked like a charm.
(actually my autochk.exe was also corrupted.Since check disk can only be done on C: during booting as windows is installed there, I  had to retrieve it from the CD.  Everything works well now )
 
Thanks a lot anyway!